# 2009 Volkswagen Jetta TDI diesel 2.0L

Tags: vw, obd-ii, diesel, jetta, can-bus

I have 2009 Volkswagen Jetta TDI diesel 2.0L, they saying this car required CAN bus system instead kwp2000.

My question is:

How does the protocol Id change? Maybe ECU is defective? Some people told me that OBD2 talking with different module from ECU.

from the car:

- Protocol: KWPS8FE9 ( should be CAN )
- ECU Address(es): 1A
- CAL ID(Calibration ID): 02F300050D 1402 ( they say wrong CAL ID )
- CAL CVN(Calibration Verification Number): 21DB ( they say wrong CAL CVN )

If you look at those monitors not supported.

OBDII Readiness Monitor Details:

- Misfire Monitor Supported: N
- Fuel System Monitoring Supported: N
- Component Monitor Supported: Y
- Catalyst Monitor Supported: N
- Heated Catalyst Supported: N
- EVAP System Supported: N
- Miss Monitor Ready: NS
- Fuel System Monitor Ready: NS
- Component Monitor Ready: NS
- Catalyst Monitor Ready: NS
- Heated Catalyst Monitor Ready: NS
- EVAP Monitor Ready: NS

How is it possible ECU unit created not belong to this vehicle CAL ID (Calibration ID): 02F300050D 1402 and CAL CVN (Calibration Verification Number): 21DB ?

I went to VW dealer couple of time and system profile saying engine/powertrain computer/ module checked was done by dealer.

Could it miscommunicate protocol KWP instead of CAN protocol ?

Comment: To my knowledge, CAN is not a protocol, but rather is the network layer (Car Area Network) the protocol rides on.

Comment: Who is "they"? And as Paulster mentioned, KWP2000 is an OBD protocol that runs on CAN, so "they" are not telling you something useful.

Comment: VW dealer gave to me some diagnostic log:
Communication path: CAN/K line
Engine electronics log versions: KWP2000/TP20.

I talk to one of the tech from VW , he saying Unsupported status of every monitor is generally caused by faulty programming of the vehicle’s emissions control computer, requires the emission control computer to be reprogrammed to resolve the problem.